# How to filter pagination on input change in cakephp

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, pagination

I have JS calendar and I need to implement when user click on date pagination needs to filter to show events on that date only without refreshing page.

JS calendar writes current selected date in input box inside form.

Comment: have you trued anything?

Comment: @sgt Yes I made it working with refreshing page but I don't have clue how to start to update without refreshing and I couldn’t find anything similar online.

Comment: if you are displaying them in tabular form. then you can try data tables. it will make it easy.